# Unit test pyspark code using python

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark

I have script in `pyspark` like below. I want to unit test a `function` in this script.

```
def rename_chars(column_name):
    chars = ((' ', '_&'), ('.', '_$'))
    new_cols = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), chars, column_name)
    return new_cols


def column_names(df):
    changed_col_names = df.schema.names
    for cols in changed_col_names:
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(cols, rename_chars(cols))
    return df
```

I wrote a `unittest` like below to test the function.

But I don't know how to submit the `unittest`. I have done `spark-submit` which doesn't do anything.

```
import unittest
from my_script import column_names

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

cols = ['ID', 'NAME', 'last.name', 'abc test']
val = [(1, 'Sam', 'SMITH', 'eng'), (2, 'RAM', 'Reddy', 'turbine')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(val, cols)


class RenameColumnNames(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_column_names(self):
        df1 = column_names(df)
        result = df1.schema.names
        expected = ['ID', 'NAME', 'last_$name', 'abc_&test']
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)
```

How can I integrate this script to work as a `unittest`

what can I run this on a node where I have `pyspark` installed?

Comment: The `unittest` issue seems to be resolved on local machine, how to use `pip` `anaconda` to create a virtualenv on the server is a different topic, you might create a different thread to make the installation, test and developing on the server,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Pyspark Unittests guide**

1.You need to [download](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) Spark distribution from site and unpack it. Or if you already have a working distribution of Spark and Python just install **pyspark**: `pip install pyspark`

2.Set system variables like this if needed:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/home/eugene/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6"
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python/:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH"
export PATH="SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

I added this in .profile in my home directory. **If you already have an working distribution of Spark this variables may be set.**

3.Additionally you may need to setup:

```
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--jars path/to/hive/jars/jar.jar,path/to/other/jars/jar.jar --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true --master local[*] pyspark-shell"
PYSPARK_PYTHON="/home/eugene/anaconda3/envs/ste/bin/python3"
```

**Python and jars? Yes.** [Pyspark uses py4j](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/PySpark+Internals) to communicate with java part of Spark. And if you want to solve more complicated situation like [run Kafka server with tests in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48416454/8442366) or use TestHiveContext from Scala like in the example you should specify jars.
I did it through Idea run configuration environment variables.

4.And you could to use `pyspark/tests.py`, `pyspark/streaming/tests.py`, `pyspark/sql/tests.py`, `pyspark/ml/tests.py`, `pyspark/mllib/tests.py`scripts wich contain various TestCase classes and examples for testing pyspark apps. In your case you could do (example from pyspark/sql/tests.py):

```
class HiveContextSQLTests(ReusedPySparkTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        ReusedPySparkTestCase.setUpClass()
        cls.tempdir = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        try:
            cls.sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf()
        except py4j.protocol.Py4JError:
            cls.tearDownClass()
            raise unittest.SkipTest("Hive is not available")
        except TypeError:
            cls.tearDownClass()
            raise unittest.SkipTest("Hive is not available")
        os.unlink(cls.tempdir.name)
        _scala_HiveContext =\
            cls.sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.test.TestHiveContext(cls.sc._jsc.sc())
        cls.sqlCtx = HiveContext(cls.sc, _scala_HiveContext)
        cls.testData = [Row(key=i, value=str(i)) for i in range(100)]
        cls.df = cls.sc.parallelize(cls.testData).toDF()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        ReusedPySparkTestCase.tearDownClass()
        shutil.rmtree(cls.tempdir.name, ignore_errors=True)
```

but you need to specify --jars with Hive libs in PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS as described earlier

or without Hive:

```
class SQLContextTests(ReusedPySparkTestCase):
    def test_get_or_create(self):
        sqlCtx = SQLContext.getOrCreate(self.sc)
        self.assertTrue(SQLContext.getOrCreate(self.sc) is sqlCtx)
```

**As I know if pyspark have been installed through `pip`, you haven't tests.py described in example.** In this case just download the distribution from Spark site and copy code examples.

Now you could run your TestCase as a normal: `python -m unittest test.py`

**update:**
Since spark 2.3 using of HiveContext and SqlContext is deprecated.
You could use SparkSession Hive API.

Comment: For me the problem is I cannot install `spark` in my edgenode. I have `native python` installed in my edgenode and cloudera provided `anaconda` to use for `pyspark` I want to run the `unittest` on the edge node using `spark` provided by cloudera.

Comment: just curious, what is the `jar` file related here?

Comment: @Gang I've described in answer.

Comment: @user9367133 as ksindi said, just install `pyspark` in your `anaconda` distribution and run tests trough `python -m unittest script.py`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a lightweight way to test your function.  You don't need to download Spark to run PySpark tests like the accepted answer outlines.  Downloading Spark is an option, but it's not necessary.  Here's the test:

```py
import pysparktestingexample.stackoverflow as SO
from chispa import assert_df_equality
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def test_column_names(spark):
    source_data = [
        ("jose", "oak", "switch")
    ]
    source_df = spark.createDataFrame(source_data, ["some first name", "some.tree.type", "a gaming.system"])

    actual_df = SO.column_names(source_df)

    expected_data = [
        ("jose", "oak", "switch")
    ]
    expected_df = spark.createDataFrame(expected_data, ["some_&first_&name", "some_$tree_$type", "a_&gaming_$system"])

    assert_df_equality(actual_df, expected_df)
```

The SparkSession used by the test is defined in the `tests/conftest.py` file:

```py
import pytest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def spark():
    return SparkSession.builder \
      .master("local") \
      .appName("chispa") \
      .getOrCreate()
```

The test uses the `assert_df_equality` function defined in the [chispa](https://github.com/MrPowers/chispa) library.

Here's [your code](https://github.com/MrPowers/pysparktestingexample/blob/master/pysparktestingexample/stackoverflow.py) and [the test](https://github.com/MrPowers/pysparktestingexample/blob/master/tests/test_stackoverflow.py) in a GitHub repo.

pytest is generally preferred in the Python community over unittest.  [This blog post](https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/testing-pytest-chispa/) explains how to test PySpark programs and ironically has a `modify_column_names` function that'd let you rename these columns more elegantly.

```py
def modify_column_names(df, fun):
    for col_name in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(col_name, fun(col_name))
    return df
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it. In the CLI call:

```
python -m unittest my_unit_test_script.py
```

**Code**

```
import functools
import unittest

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext


def rename_chars(column_name):
    chars = ((' ', '_&'), ('.', '_$'))
    new_cols = functools.reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), chars, column_name)
    return new_cols


def column_names(df):
    changed_col_names = df.schema.names
    for cols in changed_col_names:
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(cols, rename_chars(cols))
    return df


class RenameColumnNames(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        conf = SparkConf()
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
        self.sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

    def test_column_names(self):
        cols = ['ID', 'NAME', 'last.name', 'abc test']
        val = [(1, 'Sam', 'SMITH', 'eng'), (2, 'RAM', 'Reddy', 'turbine')]
        df = self.sqlContext.createDataFrame(val, cols)
        result = df.schema.names
        expected = ['ID', 'NAME', 'last_$name', 'abc_&test']
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)
```

Comment: It doesn't work: Expected :['ID', 'NAME', 'last.name', 'abc test']
Actual   :['ID', 'NAME', 'last_$name', 'abc_&test']

Comment: @EugeneLopatkin the question is not about fixing the unittests correctness :-)

Comment: @ksindi Your solution work if I have `pyspark` and `hadoop` installed in my local machine. But for me the problem is if I run this script on `edge node` then the job fails with `No module error pyspark` as in my python I don't have `pyspark` installed. `How can I use the existing  Hadoop environment and cloudera given anaconda to run the unittest`

Comment: @user9367133 you can `pip install pyspark` as of spark 2.3. maybe add it as a dependency?

Comment: @ksindi if I install using pip will it get necessary binaries

Comment: @user9367133 yes it should

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `pyspark` installed (e.g. `pip install pyspark` on a venv), you can use the class below for unit testing it in `unittest`:

```
import unittest
import pyspark


class PySparkTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("testing")
        cls.sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
        cls.spark = pyspark.SQLContext(cls.sc)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.sc.stop()
```

Example:

```
class SimpleTestCase(PySparkTestCase):

    def test_with_rdd(self):
        test_input = [
            ' hello spark ',
            ' hello again spark spark'
        ]

        input_rdd = self.sc.parallelize(test_input, 1)

        from operator import add

        results = input_rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split()).map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(add).collect()
        self.assertEqual(results, [('hello', 2), ('spark', 3), ('again', 1)])

    def test_with_df(self):
        df = self.spark.createDataFrame(data=[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']], 
                                        schema=['c1', 'c2'])
        self.assertEqual(df.count(), 2)
```

Note that this creates a context per class. Use `setUp` instead of `setUpClass` to get a context per test. This typically adds a lot of overhead time on the execution of the tests, as creating a new spark context is currently expensive.